# having issues with retracing path

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new to unity. Objective of code is to make a game object retrace a path.I am trying to make a code which saves the path of player controlled game object ,on pressing 'A', game object is re-positioned to starting point & then moves according to path saved.

Code is able to save the input (checked using Debug.log), it also move to staarting position. But doesn't move according to path saved.

Game object always moves from(0,0,0) to (-0.7,0,0) irrespective of input (even if I don't give any input & directly press 'A').

I may have made a silly mistake. Sorry for the trouble.
Here is the complete code.

```
    var pt1 = new Array ();     //key press time
    var pr1 = new Array ();     //key press release
    var pkh1 = new Array ();    //key press horizontal component
    var pkv1 = new Array();     // key press vertical component
    var level : int = 0;
    var i : int = 0;    // i is car number of this script
    var t1 : float = 0;
    var j1 : int = 0;
    var downUp;
    var heldUp;
    var upUp;
    var downDown;
    var heldDown;
    var upDown;
    var downLeft;
    var heldLeft;
    var upLeft;
    var downRight;
    var heldRight;
    var upRight;
    var downSpace;
    var heldSpace;
    var upSpace;

    var stopwatch : System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch  = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    var stopwatch1 : System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch  = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    var l = true;
        var speed : float = 6f;            // The speed that the player will move at.

        private var movement : Vector3;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
        private var playerRigidbody : Rigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
        function Awake () {
          playerRigidbody = GetComponent (Rigidbody);
        }
        function move (h : float, v : float)
        {
    // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
    movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

    // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
    movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
    playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
    }



    function Start () {
    stopwatch.Start();
    }

function FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Store the input axes.
    var h : float = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
    var v : float = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

    // Move the player around the scene.
    move (h, v);

}

function Update () 
{
    if(l) 
    {
    //for current player car
        downUp = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow);
        heldUp = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow);
        upUp =  Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow);
        if(downUp) 
        {
            pt1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            pkh1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
            pkv1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        }
        if(heldUp) 
        {
        }
        if(upUp) 
        {
            pr1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            j1++;
        }
        downDown = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow);
        heldDown = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow);
        upDown =  Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow);
        if(downDown) {
            pt1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            pkh1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
            pkv1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        }
        if(heldDown) {
        }
        if(upDown) {
            pr1[j1]= stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            j1++;
        }
        downLeft = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
        heldLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
        upLeft =  Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
        if(downLeft) {
            pt1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            pkh1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
            pkv1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        }
        if(heldLeft) {
        }
        if(upLeft) {
            pr1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            j1++;
        }
        downRight = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow);
        heldRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);
        upRight =  Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow);
        if(downRight) {
            pt1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            pkh1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
            pkv1[j1] = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        }
        if(heldRight) {
        }
        if(upRight) {
            pr1[j1] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            j1++;
        }
        downSpace = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A);
        heldSpace = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
        upSpace =  Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A);
        if(downSpace || heldSpace) 
        {
            transform.position = Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            l = false;
            stopwatch1.Start();
            j1 = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        t1 = stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.Log(j1);
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
        if(pt1[j1] <= t1) {
            while(pr1[j1] >= t1) {
                move(pkh1[j1], pkv1[j1]);   
            }
            j1++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I definitly suggest to redo that code. I see no reason for all those bools. Just write `if(Input.GetKey(...)){ ... }` etc. directly. For debugging I suggest to make your `pkh1` and `pkv1` public so you can see it's data on runtime.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your idea correctly, but I think you try to follow the input you get with `Input.GetAxisRaw` which will be either -1, 0 or 1 so no actual positions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a parent game object anywhere in this equation? If so you might have to use transform.localPosition instead of transform.position

Comment: currently there is just one game object in whole project on which I added this script as component.

Comment: so I suppose both transform.localPosition & transform.position will work same way,am I right?

Comment: Yep, I think so, the problem might be a little more complex than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use game objects to define a path or course, and simply make your script tell the player to move towards a current target, which you can set as the next object in the course.

You can lay of the path visually and the code for moving towards points in a laid our course is going to be simple and have less room for errors.

Something along the lines of:

Define a list of game objects that are the course 1-x

Player set current target to 1

Player move to current target

When player reaches current target(you could manage this with collision detection) increment current target +1 to start moving to the next target.

Just a thought.

Comment: nice suggestion, but I have to use it in street car racing type of game. keeping in consideration all the rotations, number of positions & types of cars can be ,there would be a lot of game object. I don't think it will be a feasible option.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah the method I suggested would be better suites for something like a floating platform moving along a defined path.